# expected end of string, got 'IS'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Symfony throw exception Query parse:
Error: Expected end of string, got 'IS'

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT a,
    s2.id AS id_service,
    s2.priority AS priority,
    m.name AS map_name, m.id AS id_map
  FROM GameServerBundle:Server\Server a
    LEFT JOIN a.services ss
    LEFT JOIN ss.service s2
    LEFT JOIN a.map m
    LEFT JOIN a.modification mod
  WHERE a.isBanned = 0
  ORDER BY ss.serviceId IS EMPTY, priority DESC
');
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ss.serviceId IS EMPTY` is not valid.

Comment: I know it)How to do?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I trying do order by fields which field ss.serviceId is null

Comment: In ascending order, NULL values will always be sorted last